# How can I count downloads?

Tags: php, mysql, download, counter

I coded a script that shows an advert before a download starts passing the ID of the file (stored in a db) via $_GET. Now I want to count how many times each file is downloaded and save the number in the db. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to count the number of visits to the advert page or the actual number of downloads (or download starts, to be precise)?

Comment: The number of downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add column to your files table, which would store number of downloads. You should increment it on every download of each file.

Comment: I already did this, but how do I actually count the number of downloads?

Comment: Do it in script which displays an advert. Select row from database basing of file id, get number of download, increment it and issue UPDATE command.

Comment: But how do I "get the number of downloads"? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: OK. Say advert script is `get.php`. Getting file of index _i_ is `get.php?file=i`. Then you search your files table for a row which id is _i_. In this table there should be a _count_ column or something. Take it from results returned by your database engine, increment it and update your table. This is most newbie explanation.

Answer (score 1):

after the seeing the ad you redirect the user to a php file like this:

```
$result = file_get_contents($filenames[$_GET['file_id']] . '.txt');
mysql_query("UPDATE files SET downloads = downloads+1 WHERE `file` = ".$_GET['file_id']);
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text_file.txt"');
echo $result;
```

Comment: should sanitize & check type of ALL variables that touch MySQL query's

Comment: it's just a simple script to get the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a database table listing the download IDs, then use something like:

```
$pdo->prepare("UPDATE files SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = ?")
    ->execute(array($_GET["id"]));
```